# Inline Blocks and Text Wrapping with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to display a checkbox, followed by some text that wraps around below itself. The HTML without any CSS looks as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<div>Long text description here</div>
```

I want it to display similar to:

```
X   Long Text
    Description
    Here
```

It currently wraps around like this

```
X   Long Text
Description Here
```

This is easy to do with tables, but I need it to be in CSS for other reasons. I thought a combination of display: inline-block / float: right / clear / spans instead of DIVs would work, but I've had no luck so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the checkbox and label in a container div (or li - i do forms with lists often) and apply

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="agree" />
  <label for="agree">I agree with checkbox</label>
</div>




.checkbox input {
      float:left; 
      display:block;
      margin:3px 3px 0 0;
      padding:0;
      width:13px;
      height:13px;
     }

.checkbox label {
      float:left;
      display:block;
      width:auto;
     }
```

Comment: The HTML was part of a list of similar items, so this approach worked well. I added a clear: left; for each list item or the items started to stagger, but I didn't use display:block

Comment: Could you provide an example of this working? As far as I can see, this doesn't achieve the desired results (I see long lines pushed beneath the checkbox): http://jsfiddle.net/h8uKN/

Comment: +1 for Chris, sorry, but the solution provided doesn't work in chrome and is as such not really a solid solution.

Comment: The following provides a solution for the same issue by using margin-left: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942110/how-to-disable-text-wrapping-around-checkbox . In short, the easiest solution is to give a margin-left (or right if the box is on the right) to the label with a min-width that is equal to the width of the checkbox.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
input { float: left; }
div { margin-left: 40px; }
```

Tune the `margin-left` to how much space you want. The `float: left` on the checkbox basically takes it out of the block layout so it doesn't push down the text.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct description of what floats actually do. This approach works too.