# how to disable text wrapping around checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, word-wrap

how can I prevent the text from wrapping around the checkbox? I need to align the text after the checkbox, and not under it. I know I'm not the first person to ask, but I cant seem to find a solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/csYPu/77/

```
.sign-newsletter {
padding:40px;
width:200px;
}

form li {display:inline;}

fieldset {border:0;}

.checkbox {
width: 13px;
height: 13px;
padding: 0;
margin:0 10px 0 0;
vertical-align: bottom;
position: relative;
top: -2px;
*overflow: hidden;
}

input {background:#636566; padding:7px;
width:100%;
margin-bottom:5px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

<div class="sign-newsletter">

<form method="post" action="submit-sign-newsletter.php">
    <fieldset>

        <ul>
            <li><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /></li>
            <li><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></li>
            <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="sign_me_in" value="" /><label>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur      </label></li>
            <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /></li>
        </ul>

    </fieldset>
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/csYPu/77/ the space under the checkbox should be empty, in this case, the word "amet" on the second line would start right under "Lorem"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try changing:

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <div class="chkLabel">
       <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="sign_me_in" value="" />
       <label>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</label>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.chkLabel input { float: left; margin-top:0.5em;}
.chkLabel label { display: block; margin-left: 1.5em;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/csYPu/80/)

Comment: it breaks the layout. I need the entire block to have a specific width

Comment: @devotchkah updated! (tested in IE, FF, Ch) I hope it will be helpful