# Ensuring label and checkbox start on the same line

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a simple way to do this?  I have a checkbox and some text defined like so in an aspx file:

```
<div id="div01" class="someClass" runat="server">
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox01" Checked="True" runat="server" />
 <asp:Label ID="lblSomeText" runat="server" Text="" meta:resourcekey="lblSomeText1"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

..the problem is that when rendered we have a checkbox and a span, and when the label's text is long enough the checkbox appears above the label, rather than at the left.  The resulting html structure looks like:

```
<div>
 <input type="checkbox"></input>
 <span>some fairly long text</span>
</div>
```

I'd like to force that checkbox to be on the same line as the label no matter the text length.  I can do this in html easily enough but is there a way to ensure it when coding the web components?  I'm not a CSS pro and have tried some `float:left` and `float:right` stuff to no avail.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942110/how-to-disable-text-wrapping-around-checkbox/14942294#14942294

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it didn't work in this case.  Frustrating!